# QGIS raster color selection

Tags: qgis, raster, color, point

I'm working with a raster map that looks like this:

[image: map]

Do you know any way to select the red/blue spots or ideally put a points on them? I've been browsing web and qgis help for a while now, but I haven't found anything useful as of yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes I face similar issues, though I do need to get polygons from the images. My current solution is as follows:

1. Use the `info tool` to get the specific RGB values of the areas of interest
2. Use the `raster calculator` to change the value of all areas of interest to 1 while the rest of the image is 0 (e.g. `image@1=255 AND image@2=167` - this gives all pixels with RGB 255,167,xxx out as 1 while the rest becomes 0).
3. Use the `contour` dialogue to convert the black-and-white image to contourlines.
4. Convert the contour lines to polygons
5. In your case: Get the `centroids` of the polygons.

Comment: In my case, converting using `Raster->Conversion->Polygonize` gave a better result for my usecase, future reader of this answer can try both approach `contour` or `polygonize` to find out which method outputs polygon suited for their case. To avoid unintended processing error, I encourage to match all the bands available (`@1, @2, @3` for RGB except transparency, `@4`)

Comment: Do note that the resulting raster will be inaccurate to a few pixel due to image compression artifact in the border between color(s), depending on the resolution of your source raster and accuracy needed you may need to inspect the resulting polygon against the original raster.